# Abstract system with unified rules

Tags: game-recommendation

I'm looking for a system which would provide the mechanical advantages of Fate without having to embrace the full philosophy of this game.

Let me explain. In the past months, I've been reading a lot of Fate material. Today, I'm lukewarm about it.
Originally I got interested by several things:

- Rolls are dead simple, everything is solved by a 4DF roll so you are never stopped by having to figure out what you should roll or what's the result.
  I'm not a dice roller, dice should be a tool, not a goal. Story is the goal.
  Dice should be there to provide the element of suprise or answer the players when they can't agree on what a good outcome of an action should be (you're playing an RPG, not collaboratively writing a book).
- The simplest way to grade skills. 0 to +5 most of the time. Seriously it cannot get any simpler.
- Fudge dice behave like a bell curve centered on zero, which is like the most widely usable statistical distribution. Other systems (like GURPS with the 3D6 rolls) tries to *emulate* that, a 4DF roll just *does* that.
- Aspects and their use in conflicts. You don't know how to handle such modifier? Easy! Make it an aspect! The Fate point economy will take care of balance, because once a player has spent all her FPs then she has no bonus left to claim.
- Zones in Conflict. Seriously that idea is awesome. Divide the conflict area into stuff that makes sense, and that's all. That makes *every* move in a fight important. And with some abstract thinking it's applicable to mental/psychological/social fights (although I think the Fate Core book should have presented a *detailed* example of such a conflict)

These are the things that I know now that I don't like about Fate Core:

- Stunts. I feel they are a "wart", some addendum that really doesn't feel "core" to me. I mean they could be useful if we didn't have aspects, but there's nothing a stunt can do that an aspect invocation cannot, and you loose the nice auto-balancing property hereabove mentioned. As for the "narrative effects" of some stunts, well, I don't need to have something written on my sheet to propose some story element to the other players. I need to show them that it makes sense (based on the aspects in play), and if they agree, it simply happens. Or GM tells me "pay a FP for declaring that story element". No need for writing that explicitely.
  Everything else in the game seems to "trim the fat" and allow to quickly drive a character sheet to a point, whereas stunts are about adding stuff that can already be induced from your aspects, and proposed or invoked when needed.
  In an Atomic Robo game, yeah, I get that they fit the expected game feel. But they definitely don't fit any game, that's why I don't like stunts *as a core mechanic*. They're not needed enough to be core.
  You want players to be able to claim more bonuses or give more story details? Why not just give them more FPs? That would unify stunts with aspects, and simplify core rules.
- The "let's skip the rolls" lingering demeanor (warning, it's mostly about stunts again). As I said, I don't like rolling just for the sake of rolling, but I love what dice can bring in terms of unexpected yet sensible story elements. I don't think it's fair to let a player declare that something happens without making him either convince the other players or roll for it.
  So I'm completely against stunts that go "Once per scene/session, I can say that my character does X, poof, just like that, because I want it".
  I would personally totally refuse that somebody resorts to an easy "It happens I know a dude here who owes me one" every single session.
  But it seems to be a common stunt type in Fate settings and supplements, which is why "doing without it" is not really that obvious.
  You've got a high Contacts skill? Use it. *Roll* to know whether you *actually* know somebody there. Oh success at a cost? Well, yes you know him but it turns out you forgot that he also hated you and won't help you that easily. IMHO that's much less gratuitous and more interesting narratively speaking. And funnier. Not deciding what happens is fun. And for the times when we want to decide what happens, then we don't need rules to tell us how to do it. We just *decide*.
- The constant DIY approach (or the "toolbox" approach). Fate is abstract. It's not generic in the way GURPS or Hero are generic. Fate doesn't try to model every single possibility and have a rule for everything. So then why isn't it possible to fix a set of sufficiently abstract rules that would encompass everything? Fate goes in that direction of course, but it's like nobody agrees on the way to do common stuff. Shooting somebody when an obstacle can be in the way? No consensus. Poison or recurrent sources of damage? No consensus. There are systematically several ways to do what you want to do. A lot of aspects of Fate simplify GM's work, but this actually makes it harder.

So a very long post, and I don't want to be mistaken for a troll. I know that lots of Fate players like the game as it is and it's great if they have found what they wanted in an RPG. I was just explaining what *I* am looking for. I know the game Mythic is close in spirit to what I want, but I'm not a fan of having to look at a resolution table every time I roll. Plus Mythic doesn't really have something that fills the same bill as Fate aspects.

Comment: Unfortunately we changed our policies a week or two ago such that game/system recommendation questions are no longer on topic.

Comment: If you’re interested in *why*, the short answer is that they caused a lot of problems that required a lot of moderator attention, and despite *getting* that attention, still were rarely generating answers that questioners were finding useful. The long answer is [here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5747/4563).

Comment: I was interested in why. Thanks. Although I did spend a good 30 minutes to write that ^^

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The meta about this **is** featured on the right, but that’s unfortunately as much visibility as we can give it.

Comment: The time spent writing needn't be a waste though; this post would fit just fine on one of the forums that are linked to in the close notice on the post. Good luck!